# Is there any benefit of continuous integration in small dev teams?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, collaboration

Does it make a sense to use a build server in a small (2-3 developer) game development team? I like the idea of continuous integration, and the team members are not in the same place, so it might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Continuous integration is beneficial even if there is one person doing development simply because it tests the product on a "clean" non-development machine. The benefits increase with number of developers. So the answer is "yes, it makes sense".

Comment: I think, however, that your question does not seem to be a good fit for SO - it's too vague and open-ended.